# Xcode Interface Builder Click + Drag Sticking

Tags: objective-c, xcode, click, interface-builder, mouse

I am attempting to use Xcode on Mavericks, but I am having a very peculiar problem. It seems as though my click locations are getting stuck and causing every click to be recognized at a click + drag. It's very strange and therefore somewhat hard to explain so I captured the problem within a QuickCast:

http://quick.as/a0jVc20J

I have tried using another mouse and I still have the problem. I have tried reinstalling Xcode and the problem persists. The mouse works fine elsewhere, and I do not have any other problems akin to this in any other app. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am desperate: as you can see, it is impossible to build an interface with this mouse situation.

Thanks!

Comment: make sure your mouse is functioning correctly. Try to change to another mouse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have tried that. I used a different mouse and had the exact same error. It ONLY happens in Xcode Interface Builder. Even in the Xcode code files (.m and .h's) it works just fine.